# How to do conditional update of Azure Table Storage Entity with ETag

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

How do I use the ETag of Azure Table Storage Entity to update the entity if the ETag has not changed?

Example:

```js
   var query = (from ent in cloudservicetable.CreateQuery<CloudServiceTableEntity>()
               where ent.PartitionKey == "test"
               && ent.Status == "creating"
               && ent.Counter> 0
               select ent).AsTableQuery();



    var candidates = query.OrderByDescending(s=>s.Counter).ToList();
    bool found = false;
    while (!found && candidates.Any())
    {
        //Find best candidate
        var candidate = candidates.First();

        //If we can decrement the count with out the entity have been changed
        //it is a acceptable candidate.
        candidate.Counter--;
        var opr = TableOperation.Merge(candidate);
       // cloudservicetable.ExecuteAsync(opr) 
       // How do I only do the merge if the etag have not changed?

       //TODO If changed remove/update the candidate list

    }
    // if found we have a candidate
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For conditional merges, you don't have to do anything. Your code will throw an error (`PreCondition` failed - `Http Status Code 412`) if during the merge operation `ETag` doesn't match. So your code above will work perfectly fine.

For unconditional merges, you would need to manually set the `ETag` property of the entity to `*`.

Comment: that explains why I could not find it!Thanks